# How to transfer user log in automatically into terminal server?

Tags: terminal-server, roaming-profile

I have a network setup where a user logs into a local station then starts a remote desktop session into a terminal server when they can do their work.

Now what I'm trying to do is changing the profile setup to roaming profile to help me overcome some terminal server space issues.

Now what I'm trying to do is instead of having the user to log in onto a local computer and then have them manually starts a remote desktop session to the terminal server, I want so set up either a future or a script that will automatically detect the initial log in information and automatically start a remote desktop session without the user awareness. More then they log off a terminal server it automatically log them off the local PC. this will cut the log in process for the users from two to one and also will eliminate confusion on the user end and the local PC will look like it is one PC and not 2.

How can I accomplish that? do I need a script for this or does Windows offer a solution for it? if a script is needed is there a script that I can use that is available online?

Comment: What you are asking for is a thin client, its quite possible to convert a normal x86 pc into a thin client.

Comment: not sure if you have a Software assurance license with micorsoft  or not but if you do then wintpc from microsoft is free and quite easy to configure.

Comment: @tonyroth, some of my local PC are thin Clients but some of them are regular PCs. How can I accomplish the log in idea knowing that we have those already?

Comment: @tonyroth, I missed you last post by seconds I guess :)  I am checking  to see if we have that licence available or not. Let me ask you aquestion regarding thr wintPc. Do we install it on the local "thin PC" Or PC and when they log in it automaticly connects to the terminal server? or WintPC is installed on a server? My terminal servers are old and use Windows Server 2003. Thanks

Comment: @tonyroth I don't have that licence. What is an alternative solution?